# JAVA - Best way to load attribute and element data of XML to Object variable

Tags: java, xml

I have XML file format as below:

```
<MyXML>
<Description>
<E1s Id = "Development007" Depend = "" Description = "Sample Content">
<E1 D1 = "include" RefObj = "" Val = "URL" Val1 = "" Val2 = ""></E1>
<E2 ExpD1 = "waitForElementPresent" Target = "link=PFLEGE" ExpVal = ""></E2>
<E1 D1 = "click" RefObj = "skincare" Val = "" Val1 = "" Val2 = ""></E1>
<E2 ExpD1 = "waitForElementPresent" Target = "xpath=(test)[2]" ExpVal = ""></E2>
</E1s>
</Description
<MyXML>
```

Using Java, I am trying create an object and save all XML data (including attributes and Element) as variables.

Please suggest me the appropriate parser and way to achieve this.

Thank you in advance!

Good Day!

Raja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope JAXB fits to your need. Please google about JAXB.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/